# Connect Product to a Category

Tags: java, software-design, solid-principles

I'm writing my new java project and a requirement is to represent product that can belong to a category. 
I'm using a database in my project and I connect products and categories by a foreign key.
In the code, instead, I've to use SOLID design and I don't understand how can I connect products and categories.
In a first version, the code was

```
public class Product {
    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private String descr;
    private int stock;
    private float price;
    private int category;

    public Product(int anID, String aName, String aDescr, int aStock, float aPrice, int aCategory) {
        this.ID = anID;
        this.name = aName;
        this.descr = aDescr;
        this.stock = aStock;
        this.price = aPrice;
        this.category = aCategory;
    }

    public int getID() { return this.ID; }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }

    public String getDescr() { return this.descr; }

    public int getStock() { return this.stock; }

    public float getPrice() { return this.price; }

    public int getCategory() { return this.category; }

    public void decreaseStock(int x) { this.stock -= x; }
}
```

and

```
public class Category {
    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private String descr;

    public Category (int anID, String aName, String aDescr) {
        this.ID = anID;
        this.name = aName;
        this.descr = aDescr;
    }

    public int getID() { return this.ID; }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }

    public String getDescr() { return this.descr; }

}
```

... but I'm thinking that product can ***implements*** category, in order to have all information in one object and not jump between two classes...

Which is the best way to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mimic the underlying database table structure in your Java classes verbatim. The correct way to do and which every ORM approach that I worked on until now uses is as follows:

1. `Product` class stores a reference to a `Category` instance.
2. When fetching the records from a database within the data access layer you would explicitly write code  to to create a `Category` object first and then pass it to the `Product` class constructor when creating the `Product` object.

This way the Java class hierarchy  reflects the true business relationship between a `Product` and its related `Category`. This also has the advantage of abstracting the storage details from the application - consider what would happen with the approach you are currently adopting if the data were to be stored in a NoSQL database. However, by adopting the approach presented in this answer you would only need to change the Data access layers for creating the correct objects - your class design remains intact (The **O** of **Open-Closed** principle in **SOLID**).